# Can i send a slug through a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In Laravel 5 we can send slugs to urls, something like this:

```
@foreach($records as $record)
    <div class="btn-group-sm"> 
        <a href="{{ url('business/'.$record->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a >
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Would it be the same as this:

```
@foreach($records as $record)
    <div class="btn-group-sm"> 
        <a href="{{ route('businessEdit', $record->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a >
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here's the route:

```
Route::get('/business/{id}/edit', [
        'as' => 'businessEdit',
        'uses' => 'BusinessCtrl@edit'
    ]);
```

**Edit 1**

Using the url way i can send the parameter and the address looks like `domain.tld/business/4/edit` but when using the route it looks like `domain.tld/business?4` and it doesn't work.

Here's the edit func at `BusinessCtrl`:

```
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $record = Business::find($id);

        return view('Center.business.edit')->with('record', $record);

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to split the string, you can have it as ` {{URL("business/'{$record->id}/edit") }}`

Comment: I know, i don't need to do it, but i would like to know if they are the same or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route helper accepts an array as the second argument, so you will want to do this:

```
{{ route('businessEdit', [$record->id]) }}
```